# How to know whether expectation will be finite or infinite

Tags: probability, expectation

So there is this question being asked:

For $X\sim \mathrm{Geom}(p)$, find $E(2^x)$ (if it is finite) and $E(2^{-x})$ (if it is finite).

I know how to find expectation, but my doubt is regarding how to determine if expectation will be finite or not before calculating it (as is being asked by this particular question.)

Comment: You could try standard convergence tests for convergence/divergence (limit comparison comes to mind here)

Comment: For the second, $E(2^{-x}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)^kp2^{-(k+1)} \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)^kp = p\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)^k = p\frac{1}{1-(1-p))} = 1$, so you know that it is finite.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; I'm on mobile and it renders fine for me.

Comment: In any case, you can always try to calculate the expectation - if you get a finite value, then you're good; if not, then you know that expectation is infinite.

Comment: Depends on $p$.

Comment: @CheggKidd, don’t edit the content of your question once it has been answered. If you have additional questions, you can make a new post. If you want clarifications to an answer, then you should ask the author in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

$$\operatorname{E[2^X]}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{2^k(1-p)^{k-1}p}$$
The sum converges if $p>1/2$ and diverges if $p\leqslant 1/2$
$$\operatorname{E[2^{-X}]}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{2^{-k}(1-p)^{k-1}p}$$
The sum converges for all $0\leqslant p\leqslant 1$